# showing $\|x\| \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \inf \|x_n\|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

showing $$\|x\| \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \inf \|x_n\|$$ where $x_n \to x$ weakly, and we are working under a normed space.

I am given a hint that $$\|x\| = \sup_{\|\phi\| = 1} |\phi(x)|$$ where $\phi \in X^\star$.

My idea was to choose $\phi$ s.t. $\phi(x) = \|x\|$, and somehow use the hint. The hint however says that for this particular phi we have that $\|x\| \geq |\phi(x)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\phi(x_n)|$ which already is in the incorrect direction. Any guidance please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the hint tells you that $ \|x\| = \sup\{|\phi(x)|, \|\phi \|=1\}$, you can see that your problem is equivalent to proving that $|\phi(x)| \le \liminf \|x_n\|$ for each $\phi \in X^*$ of norm 1.
Now, to prove that, we can use the fact that $(x_n)$ converges weakly to write $\displaystyle |\phi(x)| = \lim_{n \to\infty} |\phi(x_n)| = \liminf |\phi(x_n)| \le \liminf \|x_n\|$ for each $\phi \in X^*$ of norm 1.

Comment: could you explain how it's equivalent to showing that please?

Comment: It is more or less the definition of a sup. For a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$, $\sup A$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Therefore, for each $M \in \mathbb R$, the statement $\sup A \le M$ is equivalent to $\forall x \in A, x \le M$. The implication from left to right is clear since $\forall x \in A, x \le \sup A$. The implication from right to left amounts to noticing that the statement $\forall x \in A, x \le M$ is expressing the fact that M is an upper bound of A. In particular, since $\sup A$ is the least upper bound, we have $\sup A \le M$.